# Symfony 3.4.11 default locale for index not working

Tags: symfony, routes, locale, default

I recently updated my symfony application from 3.2.4 to 3.4.11
After the update, the app wasn't able to route to the indexAction if the locale is missing in the url. Working with a default locale, it should be just adding the missing locale and route to the indexAction

Example:
http://127.0.0.1:8000    ->  shows "symfony is ready" start page
http://127.0.0.1:8000/de ->  shows actual indexAction

I am using annotation for routing, this is my routing.yml

```
#routing.yml
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type: annotation
prefix: /{_locale}
requirements:
    _locale: '%app_locales%'
defaults:
    _locale: '%locale%'
```

and this my controller with indexAction and route "/"

```
#AppController.php
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Content;
use AppBundle\Entity\ContentsNav;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class AppController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="app_index")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $config =     $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Configuration')->findOneBy([]);
    return $this->render('public/app/app_index.html.twig', ['config' => $config]);
}
```

What is the problem here?

**--- EDIT ---**

As requested, here is the output of php bin/console debug:router

```
 ----
 Name                              Method     Scheme   Host   Path

 _wdt                              ANY        ANY      ANY   /_wdt/{token}

 _profiler_home                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/

 _profiler_search                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search

 _profiler_search_bar              ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar

 _profiler_phpinfo                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo

 _profiler_search_results          ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results

 _profiler_open_file               ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open

 _profiler                         ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}

 _profiler_router                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router

 _profiler_exception               ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception

 _profiler_exception_css           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css

 _twig_error_test                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}

 app_blog_index                    GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/blog/

 app_blog_index_paginated          GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/blog/{page}

 app_blog_category                 GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/blog/{slug}

 app_blog_category_paginated       GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/blog/{slug}/{page}

 app_blog_post                     GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/blog/{slugcategory}/{slug}

 admin_home                        GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/

 admin_edit_configuration          GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/configuration/

 admin_category_home               GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/categories/

 admin_category_new                GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/category/new/

 admin_category_edit               GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/category/{id}/edit/

 admin_category_translations       GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/category/{id}/translations/

 admin_category_translation_add    GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/category/{id}/translations/add/{localeCategory}/{localeTranslation}
 admin_category_translation_edit   GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/category/{idParent}/translations/{id}/edit/{localeCategory}/{localeTranslation}
 admin_category_delete             DELETE     ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/category/{id}/delete/

 admin_content_home                GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/contents/{page}/{type}

 admin_content_new                 GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/content/{type}/new/

 admin_content_edit                GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/content/{id}/edit/

 admin_content_translations        GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/content/{id}/translations/

 admin_content_translation_add     GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/content/{id}/translations/add/{localeContent}/{localeTranslation}
 admin_content_translation_edit    GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/content/{idParent}/translations/{id}/edit/{localeContent}/{localeTranslation}
 admin_content_delete              DELETE     ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/content/{id}/delete/

 admin_render_blueprint            ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/content/render/blueprint/{$template_name}/{id}/{i}
 admin_file_home                   GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/files/

 admin_file_home_page              GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/files/page-{page}

 admin_file_upload                 GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/file/upload

 admin_file_delete                 GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/file/{filename}/delete/

 admin_nav_home                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/navs/

 admin_nav_new                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/new/

 admin_nav_new_remove_element      ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/new/{idRemove}

 admin_nav_edit                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/edit/{id}

 admin_nav_edit_remove_element     ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/edit/{id}/{idRemove}

 admin_nav_delete                  DELETE     ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/{id}/delete/

 admin_nav_translations            GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/{id}/translations/

 admin_nav_translation_generate    GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/{id}/translations/generate/{localeNav}/{localeTranslation}
 admin_nav_translation_update      GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/nav/{id}/translations/update/{localeNav}/{localeTranslation}
 login_route                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/login

 login_check_route                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/login_check

 logout_route                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/logout

 password_recovery                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/passwordrecovery

 password_reset                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/passwordreset/{token}

 admin_user_home                   GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/users/

 admin_user_new                    GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/user/new/

 admin_user_edit                   GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/user{id}/edit/

 admin_user_delete                 DELETE     ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/user{id}/delete/

 admin_edit_profile                GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/admin/user/profile/

 app_index                         GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/

 app_page                          GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/{slug}

 -----
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using 3.4.11? This sounds similar to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27057 which was fixed by https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27227.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I found this bug/fix, too and checked the fixed files in my app. They are identical

Comment: Can you show the output of `bin/console debug:router app_index`?

Comment: @xabbuh I added the output. I tried it even with a fresh installation of 3.4.11 and I got the same issue

Comment: 3.4.12 is released now, do you still experience the same issue? If so, could you upload a small example application somewhere? I'd be curious to investigate what's going wrong then.

Comment: I have the same issue here. Did you find a solution ?